# Proving theorem of the form ~pvq using Induction in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have a function called feedback which calculates the power of 3 (i.e)

feedback(t) = 3^t

```
primrec feedback :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
"feedback 0 = Suc(0)"|
"feedback (Suc t) = (feedback t)*3"
```

I want to prove that

> if t > 5 then feedback(t) > 200

using Induction

```
lemma th2: "¬(t>5) ∨ ((feedback t) > 200)" (is "?H(t)" is "?P(t)∨?Q(t)" is "(?P(t))∨(?F(t) > 200)")  
proof(induct t) 
   case 0 show "?P 0 ∨ ?Q 0" by simp
next 
   assume a:" ?F(t) > 200"
   assume d: "?P(t) = False"
   have b: "?F (Suc(t)) ≥ ?F(t)" by simp
   from b and a have c: "?F(Suc(t)) > 200" by simp
   from c have e: "?Q(Suc(t))" by simp
   from d have f:"?P(Suc(t)) = False" by simp
   from f and e have g: "?P(Suc(t))∨?Q(Suc(t))" by simp
   from a and d and g have h: "?P(t)∨?Q(t) ⟹ ?P(Suc(t))∨?Q(Suc(t))" by simp 
   from a and d have "?H(Suc(t))" by simp
qed
```

First I prove that

- feedback(t+1) >= feedback(t)
- then assume feedback(t) > 200, so feedback(t+1)>200
- Assume t>5
- this implies (t+1) > 5
- Also ~((t+1)>5) V (feedback (t+1) > 200) is True
- Thus if P(t) is true then P(t+1) is true

But this is not working. I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: The obvious question is why you don't just write `3 ^ t` if you want `3 ^ t`.

Comment: 3^t is just a placeholder. I will substitute with complex function once I am able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you cannot simply assume arbitrary things in Isar. Or rather, you can do that, but you won't be able to show your goal after you've done that. The things that Isar allows you to assume are quite rigid; in your case, it's `¬ 5 < t ∨ 200 < feedback t`.

I recommend using the `case` command, which assumes the right things for you. Then you can do a case distinction about that disjunction and then another one about whether `t = 5`:

```
lemma th2: "¬(t>5) ∨ ((feedback t) > 200)"  
proof (induct t) 
  case 0
  show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc t)
  thus ?case
  proof
    assume "¬t > 5"
    moreover have "feedback 6 = 729" by code_simp 
      -- ‹"simp add: eval_nat_numeral" would also work›
    ultimately show ?thesis
      by (cases "t = 5") auto
  next
    assume "feedback t > 200"
    thus ?thesis by simp
  qed
qed
```

Or, more compactly:

```
lemma th2: "¬(t>5) ∨ ((feedback t) > 200)"  
proof (induct t) 
  case (Suc t)
  moreover have "feedback 6 = 729" by code_simp
  ultimately show ?case by (cases "t = 5") auto
qed simp_all
```

If your feedback function is actually monotonic, I would recommend proving that first, then the proof becomes a little less tedious.